# JS open tag with if and close it in another one

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have react component that gets index from map function, I'm trying to open div of row tag when my index is even and close it when my index is odd

```
  render() {
    return (
        {this.props.index%2===0 && (<div className="row mt-1">)} //new row
        <div className="col-1">{this.props.title}</div>
        <div className="col-5">
          <ProgressBar
            variant={this.props.color}
            now={this.props.now}
            max={this.props.max}
            label={this.props.label}
          />
        </div>
        {this.props.index%2===1 &&  (</div>)} //end of the row
    );
  }
```

this code in not compile:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRSJG.png)

the point is that every row contain two **ProgressBar**. What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to deal with whole elements are once, not tags.

This is easier if you break it up into functions.

You can use `splice` on an array to grab two items at a time.

e.g.

```
function createRow(elements) {
    return (
        <div>
            {elements.map(createProgressBar)}
        </div>
    );
}

function createProgressBar(element) {
    return (
        <div>{element.index}</div>
    );
}

function render() {
    // ...
    const rows = [];
    while (myArray.length) {
        const thisRow = myArray.splice(0,2);
        rows.push(createRow(thisRow));
    }
    return rows;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should modify the shape of your array into something like this before trying to render it.

```
[1,2,3,4] => [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

that way it would be easier for you to wrap it inside `div`.

see the [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-mahavira-iuvls)

Code to transform your flat array into nested array:

```
  const list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  const [state, setState] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let res = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i += 2) {
      res.push([list[i], list[i + 1]]);
    }
    setState(res);
  }, []);
```

Render logic:

```
{state.map(item => {
    return (
      <div style={{ border: "1px solid black", padding: "1em" }}>
        {item.map(i => i)}
      </div>
    );
  })}
```

Comment: It is always better to include relevant code in the post itself.